# soapclient receives -AxisFault ocurred- message after Dutch government tax have moved the soap server to new datacenter

Tags: php, xml, soap

The Dutch government moved there datacenter, Digipoort WUS, to a new location and I can't get the new server to accept the XML. They indicated that, besides that, they now only accept WS-Addressing 1.0 with namespace http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing where they no longer support the older namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing. This said, the error message on submission is very unclear to me. I did some tests by on-purpose send invalid BinarySecurityToken , DigestValue's and  SignatureValue. Those errors where much more clearly and therefore maybe indicating that at least -a whole lot- of the XML is correct.

The error which I keep getting back is, translated from Dutch;
Generall error; Procesinfrastructure
The request is not conform the coupling spec and therefore not accepted at Digipoort. The error which is occurred:

```
security.wssecurity.WSSContextImpl.s02: 
com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityException: Exception 
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault ocurred while running action: 
com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerHandler$1@5ddd927a
```

If I, for example send an invalid BinarySecurityToken it reports a same general Procesinfrastructure error. but it gives a more clear message as;

The request is not conform coupling spec and therefore not accepted at Digipoort. The error which is occurred:  `The message does not contain a valid digital signature; *ASN.1 parse of certificate failed*`

So, the error, to me it seems to indicate a way different fault. Anyone familiair with such errors or does someone have any clue what can be causing this error?

The client is built on a LAMP server. As said it worked fine before the government moved the Digipoort WUS to a new server/location. The XML already was based on WS-Addressing 1.0 with namespace http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing and was accepted previously.

The SoapClient is built on overriding the php SoapClient. I think I can control lots of things but I have no idea what I need to change. The error message 'seems' to indicate an security issue. That's why I started to send wrong values in the  BinarySecurityToken , DigestValue's and  SignatureValue fields. Anyway the server pointed out clearly those errors, like  *ASN.1 parse of certificate failed*, Hash values do not match and *Decode signature failed*

The submitted request and response XML;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://logius.nl/digipoort/koppelvlakservices/1.2/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" wsu:Id="Security-Token-c07209cb-a1ef-2922-0000-4a3268f1d48e">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-Body">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>D4vAe0xfjdCyS3ZWm74suRDwd4Y=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-Action">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>ZrXMqWxfMKKh/h/PW3UxU2BJJUo=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-MessageID">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>W0iGiFN7/zT/q9RZsPmjOSUFRGE=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-Timestamp">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>etPoSe7aCA/nsdqcyXw2z+YMYL0=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-To">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>YuTCwpxUXVFx1GuxKnXjC8pr0DA=</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>SfkHyRJFwvXrKZtkTLvqfmNulh9H6sJjXih2HDDXKWwueNMg1uLcKQgR2V9UFAkMQGaeyEsOyvs/JzRVOpVK20BuocWbxTdZI3S17Xnw6y87MosGNYU4OWQ8JVkOkqxrG5fTeps3TwOPHpybwXRpgbJiMm9gYvOcGnqmKyvwsXjsaKNxP2mAkJXEamtTMPdIfdEjTibzK9aSrNmoiH+B7xYR1B1f6x5MWGKA61aIrCLQIZrTFI/PzztLDHB/AZLbcnGTm6kh3l5GuG1hEGWPxJBoufqwlNW/lq0o51a8ISWll/oT8II1LLFIA0gSrxxy3rzBoSAgyeIqieFnDguyQQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:Reference URI="#Security-Token-c07209cb-a1ef-2922-0000-4a3268f1d48e"/>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
    <wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-Action">http://logius.nl/digipoort/wus/2.0/aanleverservice/1.2/AanleverService/aanleverenRequest</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-MessageID">1107-2019-1-5d00ecf8f3f65</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-To">https://cs-bedrijven.procesinfrastructuur.nl/cpl/aanleverservice/1.2</wsa:To>
    <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-Timestamp">
      <wsu:Created>2019-06-12T12:15:53Z</wsu:Created>
      <wsu:Expires>2019-06-12T12:18:53Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wsu:Timestamp>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-Body">
    <ns1:aanleverRequest>
      <ns1:berichtsoort>Aangifte_LH</ns1:berichtsoort>
      <ns1:aanleverkenmerk>1107-2019-1-5d00ecf8f3f65</ns1:aanleverkenmerk>
      <ns1:identiteitBelanghebbende>
        <ns1:nummer>017541736L01</ns1:nummer>
        <ns1:type>LHnr</ns1:type>
      </ns1:identiteitBelanghebbende>
      <ns1:rolBelanghebbende>Inhoudingsplichtige</ns1:rolBelanghebbende>
      <ns1:berichtInhoud>
        <ns1:mimeType>application/gzip</ns1:mimeType>
        <ns1:bestandsnaam>XMLVoorbeeldbericht.gzip</ns1:bestandsnaam>
        <ns1:inhoud>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</ns1:inhoud>
      </ns1:berichtInhoud>
      <ns1:autorisatieAdres>http://geenausp.nl</ns1:autorisatieAdres>
    </ns1:aanleverRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Algemene fout</faultstring>
      <faultactor>Procesinfrastructuur</faultactor>
      <detail>
        <fault:aanleverFault xmlns:fault="http://logius.nl/digipoort/koppelvlakservices/1.2/">
          <fault:foutcode>ALS100</fault:foutcode>
          <fault:foutbeschrijving>Het verzoek voldoet niet aan de koppelvlakspecificaties en kan hierdoor niet door Digipoort worden verwerkt.

De volgende fout is opgetreden: 

security.wssecurity.WSSContextImpl.s02: com.ibm.websphere.security.WSSecurityException: Exception org.apache.axis2.AxisFault ocurred while running action: com.ibm.ws.wssecurity.handler.WSSecurityConsumerHandler$1@900c3e06</fault:foutbeschrijving>
        </fault:aanleverFault>
      </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can the error be due to the way it is calling the function? Underneath the constructor is filled with some params like crypto_method and ciphers. Would it be possible that a fault param causes such an error?

```
$options = array(
    'ssl_method'            => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS,
    'cache_wsdl'            => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'trace'                 => true,
    'soap_version'          => SOAP_1_1,
    'passphrase'            => $password,
    'local_cert'            => $ClientCertFile,
    'public_cert'           => $PublicCertFile,
    'output_canonicalize'   => false,
    'output_last_request'   => false,
    'wsa'   => array    (
            'Action' => 'http://logius.nl/digipoort/wus/2.0/aanleverservice/1.2/AanleverService/aanleverenRequest',
            //'ReplyTo' => 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous',
            'MessageID' => $MessageID,
            'To' => 'https://cs-bedrijven.procesinfrastructuur.nl/cpl/aanleverservice/1.2',
    ),
    'stream_context'        => stream_context_create(   array   (
            'ssl'   => array(
                    'crypto_method'         =>  STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
                    'ciphers'               => 'AES128-GCM-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA',
                    'verify_peer'           => false,
                    'verify_peer_name'      => false, 
                    'allow_self_signed'     => true
            )
        )
    )); 

//
$client = new Inno3DSoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```